# Why Google Maps Cordova ionic angular, only working in Android and blank in IOS?

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

[Android Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pCZH.png)

[IOS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5aIw.png)

I have enabled Google Maps for IOS and Add this line in config.xml

```
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="MY_API_KEY" />
```

Is there any solution for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command, and make sure to add your own API keys to it:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```

Please Try

Comment: I run your command, and then run "ionic cordova run android". The issue still exist in emulator